# Interaction followup only seems to send one embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm having issues sending multiple embeds in one response and I'm not entirely sure if it's my fault (mostly likely) or a bug with discord.py.
I have a list of embeds I'm trying to follow up on an initial deferral. However, my bot only seems to ever send one embed, rather than sending the full list. The full code is [here](https://github.com/M-Davies/oghma/blob/8b6d5ee3046a1823ceabfe2712c5927538709391/bot.py#L1350-L1422) but the important bits I'll describe below:

- My bot asks the discord API to defer it's response in order to conduct the multitude of REST API requests, searching and parsing it has to do. This theoretically buys me 15 minutes to respond to the user's request properly

```py
# Send directory contents if no search term given
await interaction.response.defer(thinking=True)
```

- It then does a bunch of parsing and ends up with a dictionary of some `discord.File`'s and embeds. The embeds are created using the basic `discord.Embed` format to the `responses` variable:

```py
{'files': [], 'embeds': [<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x106f3b0a0>, <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x106f3aef0>, <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x106f3b250>]}
```

- I then try to send this dictionary in a reply but it only ever seems to send one embed:

```py
print(f"SENDING RESPONSES: {responses}...")
await interaction.followup.send(embeds=responses["embeds"], files=responses["files"])
```

*See image for the singular response in the Discord UI*

Can someone please clarify for me what I should be doing or if this is a genuine bug or documentation issue in discord.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now resolved thanks to the owner of [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/9086)